# Enumerate all values sent from a form

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am trying to submit a number of values on a webpage using a form. The problem is there are so many values, and I don't know that names of them because they are dynamically generated, so I can't manually enter something like `...Request.Form["someName"]` to get its value.

So I need to do something like this:

```
foreach(var item in Request.Form.AllKeys)
{
    // Do something with values, like:
    insert item.Value into database (for example).
}
```

But the problem is, I don't think `AllKeys` is the right thing to be using here. How can I enumerate all of the values that are sent from the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a good start. You only have to get the actual value from the `Request`. The `AllKeys` returns an array of key names, iterate over it and get the value of it:

```
foreach(var key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
{
    var val = Request.Form[key]; // save it somewhere, process it
}

// Do something with values, like:
// insert item.Value into database (for example).
```

Comment: Oh thank you Patrick, this is just what I was trying to do! (I will accept the answer when the timer lets me).

Comment: why `object`? (aren't they all `string`)?